# Slick select all rows for table with no filtering

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

How can I get a collection of `JurisdictionRow` objects? I need a `SELECT * FROM jurisdiction`

```
object JurisdictionRepo extends {
  val profile = slick.driver.MySQLDriver
} with JurisdictionRepo

trait JurisdictionRepo {
  private val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[MySQLDriver] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig("pnga-master-data")
  private val db = dbConfig.db

  val profile: slick.driver.JdbcProfile
  val tableName = "jurisdiction"

  def add(jurisdictionRow: JurisdictionRow): Future[Unit] = db.run(query += jurisdictionRow).map { _ => () }

  def delete(id: String): Future[Int] = db.run(query.filter(_.id === id).delete)

  def get(id: String): Future[Option[JurisdictionRow]] = db.run(query.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)

def all() = ???

  import profile.api._

  lazy val schema: profile.SchemaDescription = query.schema

  case class JurisdictionRow(id: String,
                             parentId: String,
                             name: String,
                             code: String)

  class Jurisdiction(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[JurisdictionRow](_tableTag, tableName) {
    val id: Rep[String] = column[String](s"${tableName}_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.Length(36, varying=true))
    val parentId: Rep[String] = column[String]("parent_id", O.Length(36, varying=true))
    val name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name", O.Length(255, varying=true))
    val code: Rep[String] = column[String]("code", O.Length(255, varying=true))

    def * = (id, parentId, name, code) <> (JurisdictionRow.tupled, JurisdictionRow.unapply _)
  }

  lazy val query = new TableQuery(tag => new Jurisdiction(tag))

}
```

I would like to implement the `all` method to return all possible `JurisdictionRow` objects in the table. This seems like a common case, but the Slick documentation has not been helpful. I just need a plain old result set, no fancy filtering, etc.

Comment: in case you need, I have a simple working example at https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps (there's also a tutorial on http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/). Hope it can help in future questions :)

Comment: @pedrorijo91 thank you sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replicate what you already have in the other queries but without the filter part.

`def all = db.run(query.result)`

Have look at the *first* example:
http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/gettingstarted.html#querying